# If statement inside html email markup

Tags: php, html, email

I want to use an if statement inside some html markup.

But when I send the mail, "type" is empty, it doesn't send it at all.

Is this the correct way to use an if else statement inside some html email markup?

```
$e_body = "Er is contact opgenomen door $name." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_content = "<br><br>

                    Gegevens:<br>
                    Naam:       $name <br>
                    E-mail:     $email <br>
                    Tel:        $phone <br>";
                    if(isset($_POST['werkzaamheden'])){
                    'Type:      $select <br>';
                    }else{
                    'Type:      Niet van toepassing';   
                    }"
                    " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_reply = "    Onderwerp:  $email2
    <br>
    $commentsb<br> ";
    }
    $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **concatenate** strings. So instead of:

```
                if(isset($_POST['werkzaamheden'])){
                  'Type:      $select <br>';
                }else{
                  'Type:      Niet van toepassing';   
                }"
```

you should have

```
                if(isset($_POST['werkzaamheden'])){
                  $e_content .= 'Type:      $select <br>';
                }else{
                  $e_content .= 'Type:      Niet van toepassing';   
                }"
```